# What is the worst-case for gift-wapping algorithm (Jarvis’s Algorithm) to compute convex hull?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, testcase, convex-polygon

I have made a program to implement the Gift Wrapping algorithm of finding convex hull. Is there any way to generate a point set that  serves as the worst case  for this algorithm?

How will I generate such case?

Comment: If I am right, the worst case is when H=N, i.e. the test set is formed by the vertices of a convex polygon.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a set of points - S. When on every iteration you subtract one point from S and add this point to a convex hull and you need to check every point what still left in S.

The run time depends on the size of the output, so Jarvis's march is an output-sensitive algorithm.

So, bigger output - more time needed. And this can be achieved on the set which is convex hull of itself.

Probably the simplest way to generate such convex hull of n points it to put all points on a circle.

[image]